# Trying to Update Properties of an object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to query the database and get the first and last name of a user and use the object maping to dynamicaly add them to what should be returned to the frontend.

but after the everything i dont get the the firstname and lastname on the retuened values. find the code and what i expect below

```
const getMyCrushRequest = async (req, res) => {
    // Check if user has sent any crush requests
    const findCrush = await CrushRequest.findAll({ 
        attributes: {exclude: ['requestFrom']}, 
        where: {requestFrom: req.user.id}
    });

    // If user has not sent any crush requests
    if(!findCrush || findCrush.length == 0){
        return res.status(StatusCodes.OK).send({
            success: false, 
            message: 'you have not sent any crush requests'
        });
    }

    
    // Map the crush requests to include the first and last name of the recipient
    const requests = await Promise.all(findCrush.map(async (crush) => {
        const nameQuery = await User.findOne({ 
            attributes: ["firstname", "lastname"], 
            where: {id: crush.requestTo}
        });

        // Add the user details to the crush request object
        crush.firstname = nameQuery.firstname;
        crush.lastname = nameQuery.lastname;

        return crush;
    }));
     
    // console.log (JSON.stringify(requests))
    // Return the mapped crush requests
    return res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({
        success: true, 
        message: 'Crush request retrieved successfully', 
        requests: requests
    });
}
```

Below is the response i get

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Crush request retrieved successfully",
    "requests": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "requestTo": "d8b60bcb-c1f4-41c9-8f0b-4f3baf734b06",
            "requestStatus": "pending",
            "createdAt": "2022-12-12T16:45:02.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-12-12T16:45:02.000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "requestTo": "f6516bd8-2577-468c-9779-3f271b6a03db",
            "requestStatus": "pending",
            "createdAt": "2022-12-12T17:06:12.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-12-12T17:06:12.000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here was what i espected

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Crush request retrieved successfully",
    "requests": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "requestTo": "d8b60bcb-c1f4-41c9-8f0b-4f3baf734b06",
            "firstname": "Somename", 
            "lastname": "someorthername",
            "requestStatus": "pending",
            "createdAt": "2022-12-12T16:45:02.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-12-12T16:45:02.000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "requestTo": "f6516bd8-2577-468c-9779-3f271b6a03db", 
            "firstname": "Somename", 
            "lastname": "someorthername",
            "requestStatus": "pending",
            "createdAt": "2022-12-12T17:06:12.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-12-12T17:06:12.000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: *(Unrelated, but that’s potentially a lot of one-off requests; something to keep in mind if any sort of scale is involved.)*

Comment: Have you tried making a copy of `crush` and adding properties to that instead? I don't know the implementation details of `findAll` (perhaps some info on what `findAll` is would be helpful), but it's possible `findAll` freezes objects or makes them immutable by some other mechanism, preventing new properties from being added.